# How to call a Vue Method after data has been loaded?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I am trying to call a method after the component is mounted but it seems like the method is being fired before the data has been fed to the component.

Error i am getting:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: url_refresh is not defined"
```

My component looks like this:

```
export default {
    props: {
        columns: Array,
        url_base: String,
        url_refresh: String,
    },
    methods: {
        refresh() {
            axios.get(url_refresh)
            .then(function (response) {
                // handle success
                console.log(response);
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
                // handle error
                console.log(error);
            })
            .then(function () {
                // always executed
            });
        }
    },
    computed: {
        // URL para Editar
        url_edit: function () {
            return this.url_edit+'/edit/'+item.id
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.refresh()
    },
}
```

And I am calling it like this:

```
<nexdatatable
:columns="['Nome','Tipo de Cliente', 'Documento', 'Filiais']"
:url_refresh="`{{route('clients.refresh_table', ['tenant_id'=>auth()->user()->tenant_id])}}`"
:url_base="`{{route('clients.index')}}`"
ref="nexdatatable"></nexdatatable>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All `props` or `data` must be referenced using `this` so:

```js
axios.get(this.url_refresh)....
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, your answer was it.